# programmatically "click" a row in TableView

Tags: javafx, tableview

After adding a new row to a `TableView`, how can I programmatically "click" it?
I currently am able to select it using

```
myTable.getSelectionModel().selectLast()
```

But it seems to be purely visual. The event doesn't fire.

It only fires correctly if I click it manually.

With a button I can do

```
myButton.fire()
```

Can this not be done with a row in TableView?

Comment: selectLast() is firing selectedIndex change event as expected. At which event are you listening?

Comment: Problem solved.
Your question, in combination with a second issue that turned up, helped me solve it.  Thank you.
The problem was that I was listening with a ListChangeListener added to the selection-model's selectedIndices.
I solved it by in stead using a ChangListener, which I attach to the models selectedItemProperty.